# Two factor authentication vs. user experience

Tags: multi-factor

I'm wondering if there's any reason to implement a username/password with 2FA or, from the user's perspective, just settle with a username/2FA code. I'm trying to seek a healthy balance between the ease of a sign in process and not requiring a user to remember a (difficult) password.

Of course I know adding a password makes it more difficult but does it weigh out to the security something like Google Authenticater app also brings.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If you do the latter, it's no longer 2FA since it only requires _something you have_ (a phone/key generator), and not _something you know_ (password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend omitting password. TOTP (what you call 2FA) is usally only 6 digits long, which is not recommended as strong enough. Another problem may be, that someone may have access to the persons phone for a short time. That is not a problem, if they would need password as well. The TOTP code would change quickly, so they can't write it down and wait till they will obtain the password. But it would be a problem if it does not, because they could just log-in immediately.

Comment: I see, that indeed is a very good point I didn't think about. Thank you. +1A